# Specify range of IPs in ~/.clusterssh/clusters?

Tags: cluster-ssh

I want to add a large cluster with many consecutive IP addresses to my ~/.clusterssh/clusters. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop similar to

```
echo -n "clustername" >> ~/.clusterssh/clusters
for i in $(seq 10 99); do
  echo -n " root@192.168.1.$i"
done >> ~/.clusterssh/clusters
echo >> ~/.clusterssh/clusters
```